# How do you evaluate boolean and then execute statements in java 8 with Optional?

Tags: functional-programming, java-8, option-type

How can I refactor this snippet in Java 8 Optional? Can I use map with OrElseThrow for this? What is a cleaner way of writing this code?

```
public void updateMyDao(MyObj objToUpdate) {
    if(myOptional.isPresent()) {
      MyDao oq = myOptional.get();
      if(!oq.getReferenceId().equals(objToUpdate.getId()))
        throw new RuntimeException("Bad Move!");
      oq.setAttribute(objToUpdate.getAttribute());
      .....
      .....
    } else {
      throw new RuntimeException("Entity was not found");
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know where did you create the `Optional` object. But your current code can be shortened using `orElseThrow()`:

```
MyDao oq = myOptional.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Entity was not found"));
if(!oq.getReferenceId().equals(objToUpdate.getId()))
    throw new RuntimeException("Bad Move!");
oq.setAttribute(objToUpdate.getAttribute());
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.map()`? I don't think that `getReferenceId` returns an `Optional`.

Comment: I don't wanna combine both the exceptions. I went for your earlier answer. That was readable and exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @dkulkarni Reverted to that revision in that case.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there are three reasonable scenarios for `Optional`:

- Do something if there is a value
- Provide a default value otherwise
- The absence of a value is an error condition, in which case you want to fail fast

Your scenario falls into the last category so I would simply write:

```
  MyDao oq = myOptional.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Entity was not found");

  if(!oq.getReferenceId().equals(objToUpdate.getId()))
    throw new RuntimeException("Bad Move!");
  oq.setAttribute(objToUpdate.getAttribute());
```

Of course, it's appealing to use methods like `ifPresent`, `filter` or `map`, but in your case, why would you want to continue when the application is in a faulty state. Now if you wouldn't throw an exception if the entity wasn't found, then the situation would be different.

Something like `oq.checkMove(objToUpdate.getId())` could make sense. That would eliminate the `if` and make the code more expressive.